# jquery text field converting to uppercase/lovercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date

I have two text fields:
1 text fielf value is from db using ahax:

```
$("#p_plus_h").val(moment().add('days', prod.p_plus).format("DD MMM"));
```

and return value exmp: 29 Jun
user enter date (string) in to field two and both values must be same  (uppercase).
I know i can change cases in css but real value is still lowercase

If i enter date exp in field two 29 jun i can see 29 JUN but dates is not same becouse field 1 is 29 Jun, field two 29 jun. how to solve?

Comment: I need change both strings to uppercases realy but no make ilusion like css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method `.toUpperCase()` on the string.

```
$("#p_plus_h").val(moment().add('days', prod.p_plus).format("DD MMM").toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a methof for that: toUpperCase.

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp